# The need for id_callback when in a multithread environment?

Tags: openssl

I think `locking_callback` is enough to lock/unlock shared data structure of OpenSSL when used in multithread environment. So why need `id_callback`? That is, when OpenSSL need to call it?

Answer (score 0):

> I think locking_callback is enough to lock/unlock shared data structure of OpenSSL when used in multithread environment, so why need id_callback? that is, when OpenSSL need to call it?

OpenSSL has on the order of 40 locks. You can grep for `CRYPTO_NUM_LOCKS`. You can grep for `CRYPTO_LOCK_` to get an idea of the components that are protected, like `CRYPTO_LOCK_UI`, `CRYPTO_LOCK_X509_STORE`, `CRYPTO_LOCK_RAND`, and `CRYPTO_LOCK_ENGINE`.

Implicit threads identifiers, like using the stack address of the thread's stack, are not unique because they can be reused. For example, from [`pthread_self(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_self) man pages:

> Thread identifiers should be considered opaque: any attempt to use a
>   thread ID other than in pthreads calls is nonportable and can lead to
>   unspecified results.
>
> Thread IDs are only guaranteed to be unique within a process. A thread
>   ID may be reused after a terminated thread has been joined, or a
>   detached thread has terminated.
>   ...

So its difficult for OpenSSL to know how to get a unique identifier for a thread; and difficult to properly log and debug some multithreads problems without a unique identifier for each unique thread. Because of the subtleties of the problem, OpenSSL just pushes it back to the programmer to provide the unique id.

When using pthreads, it takes a little jiggering to get right. For example, with pthreads, you should provide a unique per-thread counter. See [How to assign unique ids to threads in a pthread wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24887601) and [Retrieve pthread_create's arg from outside the thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30159660)

---

Here are some related questions on Stack Overflow:

- [How to get thread id of a pthread in linux c program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21091000)
- [How do I get a thread ID from an arbitrary pthread_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/558469)
- [How to assign unique ids to threads in a pthread wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14125641/608639)
- [A Unique and Constant Identifier for a pthreads thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1052489)
- [Retrieve pthread_create's arg from outside the thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30159660)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "and difficult to properly log and debug some multithreads problems without a unique identifier for each unique thread", so could I say this identifier is just for log/debug purpose, and it's not necessary for lock/unlock?

Comment: @Array - OpenSSL does not have a general purpose way of getting a unique id from a thread id. One size does not fit all. You have to provide it.

Comment: Yes, I see. I have to provide the id to use OpenSSL in multithread environment. What I want to know is if this id is necessary for lock/unlock mechanism except for debug/log?

Answer (score 0):

In OpenSSL there's one error queue for each thread, so the thread id is necessary to locate it's error queue into which error code is put, I think this is one of the purpose of id_callback.